# java fx - updating texfield after togglebar change - small bug

Tags: java, javafx

I have an issue with below part of code

```
    ArrayList<Integer> baseCost = new ArrayList<>();

    priceTextField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2) {

            baseCost.add(Integer.parseInt(priceTextField.getText()));
        }
    });

    daysSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2) {

            priceTextField.textProperty().setValue(String.valueOf((int) daysSlider.getValue() * baseCost.get(0)));

        };

    });
```

Program works as follows:
I update data in form called addCar.fxml, after clicking saving button car is added to my database. I type digit in textfield, if slider is set to for example 3 textfield number updates automatically to textfield * 3

Slider value has range since 1 to 10

problem:
If I paste the number from the clipboard, for example 500, then slider is 3 I get a value 1500 - which is correct

but if I type number from the keyboard 5+0+0 program read only first digit from the texfield so if slider is 3 then I get result 15

It looks data is pulled after first digit is passed to Textfield, how can I workaround this?

Comment: `List.add` adds adds a new element to the list. `baseCost.get(0)` always reads the first one...

Comment: How can we rebuild this logic to still have required result,

Comment: after typing textfield, then changing slider, textfield updates automatically with logic textfield * slider value

Comment: Maybe I will just add one more TextField with base price

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your problem, but wouldn't a label to display price * days be a lot simpler and more intuitive from the user's perspective? Why do you want to change the text field directly?

To answer your question, change baseCost to be an int instead of a List. (I still can't quite figure out why you would need a List here, unless I'm missing something)